# A sintaxe do Meteor mudou da versão 0.8 para a versão 1.0?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, meteorjs

Dentre as diversas mudanças no Framework Meteor da versão 0.8 para a versão 1.0, sei que ele não mais utiliza o Meteorite, e que a engine de template mudou da Handlebars para Blaze. Mas a sintaxe mudou? E mais o que mudou?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

Ai tem todo o histórico de mudanças ate a presente versão(V1.1.0.2)

Comment: Parece que houve mudanças de API sim: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#api-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim a sintaxe do Meteor mudou em alguns pontos, por exemplo:

Antes da versão 1.0 a definição dos helpers era assim:

```
Template.leaderboard.player = function(){
    // code goes here
}

Template.leaderboard.goals = function(){
    // code goes here
}
```

Com a mudança ficou assim:

```
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
   'players': function(){
      // code goes here
    },
    'goals': function(){
      // code goes here
    }
});
```

Tambem ouve mudança no created, rendered e destroyed:

O que antes era assim:

```
Template.leaderboard.created = function(){

}
```

Acima de 1.0 ficou assim:

```
Template.leaderboard.onCreated({

});
```

Acompanhe as mudanças que ocorreram aqui nesse link:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#api-changes

esse link talvez possa ajudar tb:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/about-oncreated-onrendered-ondestroyed-and-helpers/165